# Looping in sql scripts to create schemas

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a bunch of duplicate schemas in PostgreSQL.  The schemas will have the same content but different names.  I want to have the commands to do this in a script, so that I can delete and rebuild as I test.  I would like to install the schemas from the command line: `psql -f script.sql dbname`.

Since I am creating a number of duplicate schemas, I think a loop in `script.sql` would be an optimal way to do this.  I could use the loop iterator variable with the schema name to ensure each duplicate schema has a different name.

From what I have read, loops must exist within functions.  If that is the case, should I define a function in `script.sql`, then call the function after its definition?  My concern with that is that this utility function will end up as part of the database.  Is this the case?  E.g. are the functions you define in the script bound to be part of the DB the script creates?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: "*using a loop in dbname*" does not make sense - at least not to me. Please show us your script content and explain what exactly you expect those "loops" to do.

Comment: updated to be more specific

Comment: Do you want the loop to run different `create schema` statements and then run the script for that just created schema?

Comment: Yes, to create the schemas and the tables that belong to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a script you can write an [anonymous code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html) using the `DO` command, using any of the available languages. The block gets executed once and is then discarded. A stub in PL/pgSQL language (the default language):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  -- Local variables go here
BEGIN
  -- Your code goes here
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```